# bot sniping tokens on pancakeswap by watching the mempool

Tags: uniswap, txpool, pancakeswap

i seen a video on youtube of a sniper bot buying tokens as soon as the token launches on pancakeswap and gets in on the same block. i have tried to use another bot that buys the tokens when the pair is created but it seems there are other bots in before the pair is created. would it be hard to code a bot from scratch that is similar to the bot in the video? thank you.

here is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeZW8Bti6Vw&t=10s

Comment: What's the real question? How long it will take depends on your skills.

Comment: For someone that does not know how to code, I would say a year or two. For someone who has experience in these kind of things, a day or two.

Comment: making the bot for pancakeswap is a piece of cake!